# Error: implicit declaration of function 'g_slist_free_full'

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, implicit-declaration

I am trying to compile some software called [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint). I had successfully compiled it on another machine but now however, in a number of files, I get the following error:

```
tomselleck@ubuntuselleck:~/Documents/FingerBellProject/libfprint-0.5.0$ sudo make
[sudo] password for tomselleck: 
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tomselleck/Documents/FingerBellProject/libfprint-0.5.0'
Making all in libfprint
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/tomselleck/Documents/FingerBellProject/libfprint-0.5.0/libfprint'
  CC       libfprint_la-aes1610.lo
drivers/aes1610.c: In function 'capture_read_strip_cb':
drivers/aes1610.c:619: error: implicit declaration of function 'g_slist_free_full'
make[2]: *** [libfprint_la-aes1610.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/tomselleck/Documents/FingerBellProject/libfprint-0.5.0/libfprint'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tomselleck/Documents/FingerBellProject/libfprint-0.5.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas? Thanks !

**Edit**

I'll post an example of the line it is throwing an error on:

```
    /* stop capturing if MAX_FRAMES is reached */
    if (aesdev->blanks_count > 10 || g_slist_length(aesdev->strips) >= MAX_FRAMES) {
        struct fp_img *img;

        fp_dbg("sending stop capture.... blanks=%d  frames=%d", aesdev->blanks_count, g_slist_length(aesdev->strips));
        /* send stop capture bits */
        aes_write_regv(dev, capture_stop, G_N_ELEMENTS(capture_stop), stub_capture_stop_cb, NULL);
        aesdev->strips = g_slist_reverse(aesdev->strips);
        img = aes_assemble(aesdev->strips, aesdev->strips_len,
            FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

        g_slist_free_full(aesdev->strips, g_free);<---- Error here

        aesdev->strips = NULL;
        aesdev->strips_len = 0;
        aesdev->blanks_count = 0;
        fpi_imgdev_image_captured(dev, img);
        fpi_imgdev_report_finger_status(dev, FALSE);
        /* marking machine complete will re-trigger finger detection loop */
        fpi_ssm_mark_completed(ssm);
        /* Acquisition finished: restore default gain values */
        restore_gain();
    } else {
        /* obtain next strip */
        fpi_ssm_jump_to_state(ssm, CAPTURE_REQUEST_STRIP);
    }

out:
    g_free(data);
    libusb_free_transfer(transfer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when

- the first use of the function precedes its definition,
- there is no prototype for the function, or
- a required header file is missing.

Make sure that there is a prototype in the text or in a header, or move the function to the front of the file, before its first use.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not very sure what you mean, I don't know too much about c... I am compiling this and then wrapping it in a java wrapper.

Comment: @Tomcelic Look up the location of the `g_slist_free_full` function in the source files. There should be two places - one in a .h file, and one in a C/CPP file. Make sure the .h file is `#include`-d at the top of the source file where you see the error.

Answer (score 0):

...also (parenthetically) don't run `make` as root, with sudo.  That's partly because one can imagine something breaking during the build which stomps on something important (which not being root would have prevented), and also on the general principle that it's good to be root as little as possible.

If you are indeed installing something in a system location such as `/usr/local`, build as yourself, then do `make -n install` and check what's going to be installed where (presuming the thing you're building has an install target).  If everything looks OK, only then do `sudo make install`.